# Hidden values in php echo

Tags: javascript, php

I have this query in php code:

```
 $sql="SELECT vName,id FROM employee WHERE vName LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY vName";
```

I have echoed the vName.

```
 echo $row['vName']."\n";
```

The above values appear in a autocomplete textbox.
In the same aboce echo statement I want to pass 'id' as hiden value. is it possible? I wan to retrieve it in another page.How do I do this?

Comment: Sure, why do not simply try to do that? (Since you're aware about `hidden` input type, I'm sure you know what to do)

Comment: HTML is used to make it hidden.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="givesomename" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT vName,id FROM employee WHERE vName LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY vName";

$hid='<input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="abc" value="'.$row['id'].'" />';

echo($hid);

echo $row['vName']."\n";
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Echo it out to a hidden input field,

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="my_hidden_id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
```

This way you can pass it with a form if you are submitting one or simply add an id to it and get the value to pass to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

I would first make a variable of $row['id'] and when you're still in your form but outside the textbox do this:

```
    <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$yourvariable."'/>";?>
```

If it must be completely hidden i recommend using php-sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do that if you want to retrieve the id in other page , you better do this :

```
<a href="your_link/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['vname'] ?> </a>
```